# The algebraic closure of an algebraic extension of a field is just the algebraic closure of the field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

**I have to show that if $K$ is an algebraic extension of a field $F$, then $\overline{K} = \overline{F}$.**

My attempt: obviously, $\overline{F} \subset \overline{K}$.

OTOH, take an element $a$ from $\overline{K}$. But because an algebraic extension of an algebraic extension is an algebraic extension, $\overline{K}$ is an algebraic extension of $F$. Therefore $a \in \overline{F}. \square$

Is there anything I need to fix or take care of? In particular, is the first statement really "obvious"?

Comment: With your global argument, what do you need to consider $a \in\overline K$ for?

Comment: @Bernard To show the other inclusion

Comment: I don't think you need any $a$. By definition, if $\overline{K}$ is algebraic over $F$, it is contained in $\overline F$.

Comment: Then is my "obvious" direction the one I had to show, and the one I showed was the actual obvious direction?

Comment: Both are ‘obvious’, in a sense. This depends on the tools you're allowed to use. This might depend on your definition of the algebraic closure of a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“The” algebraic closure of a field is not a well defined concept.

What you want to prove is that

> if $K$ is an algebraic extension of a field $F$ and $\bar{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$, then $\bar{K}$ is also an algebraic closure of $F$.

An algebraic closure of $F$ is characterized by the fact that it is an algebraically closed algebraic extension of $F$.

1. $\bar{K}$ is an extension of $F$: true, because $\bar{K}$ is an extension of $K$;
2. $\bar{K}$ is algebraically closed: true by assumption;
3. $\bar{K}$ is an algebraic extension of $F$: true, by the argument below.

If $a\in\bar{K}$, then $a$ is algebraic over $K$. But every algebraic element over $K$ is also algebraic over $F$, by well-known results.

Comment: In Dummit and Foote, the algebraic closure of F is defined as an algebraic extension in which every polynomial in F[x] splits completely. Then by this definition, I feel like the algebraic closure is well defined, so I don't know if we are talking about the same thing on your first line of your response.

Comment: @SKYejin The algebraic closure is unique only up to isomorphisms. The definition you mention is the same as mine: “every polynomial splits” is equivalent to “every polynomial of positive degree has a root”, which is what I call “algebraically closed”.