# Let L be an algebraic extension of K. Show that any algebraic closure of L is also an algebraic closure of K.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

1. A field F is said to be algebraically closed if every algebraic extension E/F is trivial, i.e., E=F.
2. so according to this theorem any extension L of K will be equal L=K.
   of the algebraic closure of L is also an algebraic closure of K.

How to prove the first part that algebraic extension of an algebraically closed field is equal?

Comment: You have given a definition of *algebraically closed*, but you haven't given a definition of *algebraic closure*, so it's not clear how you propose to prove anything about algebraic closures.

Comment: Would you like to give a counterexample, Thorgott?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416338/the-algebraic-closure-of-an-algebraic-extension-of-a-field-is-just-the-algebraic

Comment: Have you looked at the link, pankaj?

Comment: Is anybody still here? @Thorgott ? pankaj?

Comment: @Gerry apologies, it appears I had misread the title

Comment: No worries, @Thorgott I've been known to do that, too. It seems pankaj has lost interest in the question. Bye-bye, pankaj.