# Degree of algebraically closed field extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $\ell$ be a field extension of the field $k$, and let $[\ell : k] = n$ (possibly infinite). Let $\overline{\ell}$ and $\overline{k}$ be algebraic closures of $\ell$ and $k$.

Is it true that $[\overline{\ell} : \overline{k}] \leq n$ ?

Comment: If the $ [\overline{\ell} : \overline{k}]$ is finite then those algebraic closures have to be equal, i.e. the degree is $0$. Because algebraically closed field does not have algebraic extensions.

Comment: And then the answer is "yes, they are equal": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416338/the-algebraic-closure-of-an-algebraic-extension-of-a-field-is-just-the-algebraic

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.